# Spring run independent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I am running a v4 Spring mvc app with spring security 3.2
I am trying to run a independent thread from the controller

```
@Controller
    public class C1{
         @AutoWired
         C2 c2;

         @RequestMappting("/")
         public String home(){
            c2.run();
            System.out.println("something");
            return "home";
         }
    }
}

@Component
@Scope
public class C2 extends Thread{
  @Override
  public void run(){
    while(true){
       System.out.println("random stuff");
    }
  }
}
```

when I run this code it gets stuck in `c2.run();` the next line does not execute;
What i am trying to achieve here is print that `random stuff` continuously and render the home.jsp page
What am i doing doing wrong how to fix this???

Comment: Try `c2.start()` instead of `c2.run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a Thread you need to invoke `start()` method on a Thread. 
Make Following chages to your code:

```
@Controller
    public class C1{
         @AutoWired
         C2 c2;

         @RequestMapping("/")
         public String home(){
            c2.start();
            System.out.println("something");
            return "home";
         }
    }
}

@Component
@Scope
public class C2 extends Thread{
  @Override
  public void run(){
    while(true){
       System.out.println("random stuff");
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that the thread would run infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use Threads directly when using Spring Framework. It has a great [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#schedulinghttp://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#schedulinghttp://) abstraction which should be used. So what you want can be achieved.

```
@Controller
public class C1{
     @AutoWired
     C2 c2;

     @RequestMappting("/")
     public String home(){
        c2.run();
        System.out.println("something");
        return "home";
     }        
}

@Component
@Scope
public class C2{

  @Async
  public void run(){
    while(true){
       System.out.println("random stuff");
    }
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

 @Override
 public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
     executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
     executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
     executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
     executor.initialize();
     return executor;
 }

 @Override
 public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
     return MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
 }
```

}

Comment: good suggestion. but I am again getting stuck at the same place. any Idea why??

Comment: If its stuck then the execution is not in a new thread. So for my example to work correctly you need to configure the Spring Task Execution either with .xml or java-config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please post the sample code for java config??

Comment: There is a great documentation for it at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html Also I will update the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

`c2.run()` just calls the method, it doesn't start the thread. So it will run just once. Please refer to the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for starting a thread.

There are other issues to consider here, such as whether you really want to start a new background thread every time your page is requested and whether you want it to go into the tight resource-intensive loop that you have illustrated.

You've also got a typo: `RequestMappting` should be `RequestMapping`

Comment: This is for test. I am not actually going to use it. thanks for the answer though